# Connecting to SQL Server database file with Entity Framework without installing SQL Server Express on client machine

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have window application will be installed on client machine

How can I connect to a database (`.mdf`) on client machine through my window application with Entity Framework without installing SQL Server Express?

Is this available in VS 2010 or 2012

Comment: You **CANNOT** attach to a `.mdf` if you haven't installed SQL Server Express. No way. None. If you have an `.mdf` file and you want to use it (by attaching it), you ***MUST*** install SQL Server Express - no alternative.

Comment: The **proper** solution would be to have a **central server machine** on that network, put your SQL Server database there (not attaching a `.mdf` - properly creating a database and its db objects) and then have the client machines connect to that server (instead of having a `.mdf` on each client machine...)

Answer (score 0):

While creating an entity model in Data Connection section create a new connection, change Data Source and pick Microsoft SQL Server Database File.